Replace constant BLE Scanning with Efficient scanning
So I'm trying to develop an advertisement based connectionless communication system using ESP32 Dev Kit. Basically, I've an app on Android developed using Flutter using flutter_blue_plus and some other packages that can advertise certain data based on which I can make the ESP to perform actions/ send ACK through the manuf data in the advertisement which I read by scanning.
void loop() {
  pBLEScan->start(5, false);
  Serial.println("[INFO] BLE scan started");
  delay(5000);
}

To optimize power consumption, I've set the ESP to scan after every 5 second however this leads to drop of advertisement packages, greater response times, etc. How can I optimize the same? Maybe some sort of event driven scanning or so?
Thanks.
